# Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT returns multiple values

Tags: android, android-sensors

In my application (on Samsung Galaxy S3) I use the `Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT`-Sensor.

The value of values[0] is clear, it's the lux-value of the current light (This is about 40-50 in normal light ambiente).

But I also get a value from values[1].

According to the developer.android.com-Page this is not possible because there's only one value.

Now I wonder: What is this value?

Attached is a link to a screenshot, on the upper left you see the values of values[0] and values[1].

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBR5p.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the RGB light sensor values coming from the Samsung device. Since the Galaxy S3 values[1] provides an output on Samsung devices with an RGB sensor.